# Concatenation of vector elements into one 32-bit word

Tags: c++, vector, char, uint32

I am trying to concatenate a vector of four elements into a 4-byte word to represent as an uint32_t.

Sorry, I don't have my code, but this is what I am trying to do:

vector v; // each element is a byte, with four elements 
v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3] 
concatenate these four elements to form a word (I guess a char[32]?) [0][1][2][3] to use as a uint32_t.

I have tried changing v[0,1,2,3] to strings then appending the strings using loops but for whatever reason, the end results was adding erroneous bits.

Thank you so much for the help everyone!

Comment: cast the int to a char* (NOT a vector) then set char-pointer-to-my-int[0] ... [3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **bit shifting** and **bitwise OR**, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
// fill v with 4 bytes as needed...
uint32_t i = (uint32_t(v[X1]) << 24) | (uint32_t(v[X2]) << 16) | (uint32_t(v[X3]) << 8) | uint32_t(v[X4]);
```

Where `X1..X4` are the desired byte indexes in the vector, depending on which endian you want to use for the `uint32_t`.

Alternatively, if the vector elements are already in the correct byte order for the endian you want the `uint32_t` to be in, you can just `memcpy()` the bytes as-is:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
// fill v with 4 bytes as needed...
uint32_t i;
std::memcpy(&i, v.data(), 4);
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out and got me going!